# Compare two dataframes Pyspark with two columns

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to compare two data frames with have 2 number of columns

```
df1 = spark.read.csv("/path/to/data1.csv")
df2 = spark.read.csv("/path/to/data2.csv")
```

DF1

```
col_name,order
emp_id,1
emp_name,2
salary,3
```

DF2

```
col_name,order
emp_name,2
salary,3
join_date,4
```

Expected DF3:

```
col_name,order
emp_id,1
join_date,4
```

Code

```
df1.select(*).subtract(df2.select(*)).collect()
```

I tried like this but seems it missing data from df2, any solution?

Comment: how are you trying to compare them? and what is the expected output? please update your question with that detail ;)

Comment: sorry DF2 is col_name,order
emp_name,2
salary,3
join_date,4

Comment: want to remove common records from combined records to get different records

Comment: please format your quesiton properly. and edit your question with the right details please

Comment: @KSoumya I've added an answer based on your previous data, although will work perfectly on corrected data as well. Please let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `full outer join`. This will join the dfs on a specific column returning all matching records from both tables whether the other table matches or not. Then where there are rows in `df1` that don't have matches in `df2` or vice versa, those rows will be listed as well but with nulls.

So:

1. Do full outer join and assign the result to a new df `df_outer`
2. Filter `df_outer` to keep rows where the `order` value is null.

I have not tested this code. Please test it.

```
# full outer join on the two dataframes
df_outer = df1.join(df2, 
               df1.order == df2.order, 
               how="full_outer").show()
```

From `df_outer` you can filter where the `order` value is null.

Comment: make sure to join on `emp_id` or whichever column you want to join on. you dont need the `.show()` if you are assigning to a variable. I cant edit my answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

Just use left-anti join twice for each dataframe:

```
missing_right=df1.join(df2, "col_name", "left_anti").withColumn("Remark", F.lit("NOT_IN_DF2"))
missing_left=df2.join(df1, "col_name", "left_anti").withColumn("Remark", F.lit("NOT_IN_DF1"))

missing_left.union(missing_right).show()
```

Input Dataframes:

[image: In]

Output:

[image: Output]